# Spring Security OAuth2 - JWT's with Database for Clients and Users

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

To my understanding of the Spring OAuth2 implementation, the ClientDetailsConfiguration and TokenStore are not necessarily dependent. Essentially, I thought one should be able to use a JWTokenStore (where the tokens themselves are not stored in a database) with a database to house client credentials. However, while I have referenced multiple articles on the topic, most (for illustation/simplicity), simply hard code the client credentials or place them in a properties file.

For example ([source](https://medium.com/@nydiarra/secure-a-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-reference-to-angular-integration-e57a25806c50)):

```
      @Override
   public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
      configurer
              .inMemory()
              .withClient(clientId)
              .secret(clientSecret)
              .authorizedGrantTypes(grantType)
              .scopes(scopeRead, scopeWrite)
              .resourceIds(resourceIds);
   }
```

However, I am needing to actually store the client details in a database. I thought it would pretty straight forward; that is, I thought I could achieve the desired result by setting a JWTokenStore and a JDBC client back-end.

AppConfig

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;
    
    @Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
    private String dbDriverClassName;
    
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String dbUsername;
    
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String dbPassword;
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(datasourceUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
        
        return dataSource;
    }    

       @Bean
       public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
          JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
          converter.setSigningKey("123");
          return converter;
       }

    
       @Bean
       public TokenStore tokenStore() {
          return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
       }
```

AuthServerConfig

```
 @EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

 private final AppConfig appConfig; 

private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
public AuthServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AppConfig appConfig) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.appConfig = appConfig;
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
    

    configurer.jdbc(appConfig.dataSource());
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}



   @Bean
   @Primary //Making this primary to avoid any accidental duplication with another token service instance of the same name
   public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
      DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
      defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
      defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
      return defaultTokenServices;
   }
```

Rather than return a JWT, it is returning a "normal" (for lack of better term) access token:

```
    {
    "access_token": "11129068-ad5f-4440-a4d1-6501f01e100b",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 899,
    "scope": "read"
}
```

How can I use JWTs with client-credentials stored in a database?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to generate JWT token or consume and validate it?

Comment: The end goal is to both. However, the code above is for the generation piece; I am trying to separate the Authorization and Resource servers. Thanks.

Comment: `JwtTokenStore` is for validating and parsing of JWT tokens. In order to create JWT token from database you need to read information from DB and manually create JWT token using libraries like jsonwebtoken or nimbusds.

Comment: @tsokalp, thanks. However, I am truly a  bit perplexed. From the articles I  have been looking over (such as http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt & https://medium.com/@nydiarra/secure-a-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-reference-to-angular-integration-e57a25806c50) it seems that a JWTokenStore and JWTokenConverter were sufficient. What am I overlooking?

Comment: That is indeed confusing and I still dont think they are using `JwtTokenStore` to generate JWT tokens. Because if you look at their full git project they are using `findTokensByClientId` to get a new token but that method has empty implementation for `JwtTokenStore`.

Comment: Kelly, any progress on this particular question?

Comment: @diaz, yes, I actually have been able to successfully implement separate Auth and Resource servers using JWT's and clients credentials stored in the database. It has been a while since I encountered this issue, so I cannot be certain what exactly resolved it, but I would be glad to see if I could be of assistance if anyone is encountering similar issues.

Comment: @Kelly, feel free to provide an answer to your own question if you recall the solution. I personally didn't encounter your specific issue. I mainly wanted to ask about your use case regarding storing client credentials in the database. I decided against it since I have two clients for my rest API, both of which are internal (web & desktop). What is your use case for needing to store client credentials in the DB?

Comment: @diaz, good question. To be honest, for my present situation, storing client credentials in-memory would be sufficient, and, perhaps, even more sensible. However, it was concerns related to scalability that primarily prompted the decision to use a database. At one point, it appeared as if an external organization might have needed to access the API. Such ever happened, but it was a "just in case" decision. Good observation though; I suspect using a DB might be excessive for many needs. Hopefully this will provide some points to ponder for those implementing a similar structure.

Comment: @KellyMarchewa, thank you for your insight. I hope our discussion can help someone in the future as well. Cheers and Good luck on the rest of your development :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should also set accessTokenConverter to the endpoint as below.

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
             .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
             .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
             .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```